# Initializing a List<string> in C#

Tags: c#

how to make the items in a List to zero

I've a list List< String> sampleList which contains 10 items.

eg:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
0
```

how to make the list contents into zero like

```
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> SampleList=SampleList.Select(X=>"0").ToList();

Answer (score 8):

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Count; i++ )
{
    numbers[i] = 0;
}
```

Comment: +1, Simple, easy, works. Although he does claim to have a list of strings.

Comment: I wonder why the above answer same as this, which is even earlier does not get as much upvote as this.

Comment: yeah I am pissed off about that too! I beat him by like 2-3 minutes.

Answer (score 5):

Another alternative is

```
myList = Enumerable.Repeat<string>("0", myList.Count).ToList();
```

I'll admit it's certainly not better than a regular loop, but `Repeat<T>` has its uses

Answer (score 4):

?I would just iterate through the list, replacing it content (string) to "0"

Comment: @Pramodh: Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: @Pramodh, not for such a small list.

Comment: Any solution is going to involve iteration of some kind.